# How can I use csv_reader object outside like a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, stack-overflow

I want use like list or dict but i am finding this error when i tried it. How can I use csv_reader object outside like a list?

```
import csv


def get_data(file):
    with open(file,'r',encoding="ISO-8859-1") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file,delimiter=',')
        return csv_reader
for i in get_data('spam.csv'):
    print(i)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 10, in <module>
    for i in get_data('spam.csv'):
  File "/home/indianic/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 111, in __next__
    self.fieldnames
  File "/home/indianic/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 98, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `with open()` to open the file, as soon as the function block runs the file gets closed and you don't have access to it.

In order to keep the context of file you can use 2 of the following ways.

1. You can use it by yeild a generator object instead of returning.

```
import csv


def get_data(file):
    with open(file,'r',encoding="ISO-8859-1") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file,delimiter=',')

        for row in csv_reader:
            yield row

for i in get_data('spam.csv'):
    print(i)
```

2. Open the file outside of the function

```
import csv

def main():
    csv_file = open(file,'r',encoding="ISO-8859-1")
    for i in get_data(csv_file):
        print(i)
    csv_file.close()

def get_data(file):
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file,delimiter=',')
    return csv_reader

main()
```

Comment: I did second section before,I was looking for first section. Thanks.
by the way if you know another way pls ttext here.

Answer (score 0):

The `with open` construct opens the file at the beginning of the attached code and closes the file after the last line.
You may use this code:

```
def get_data(file):
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file,delimiter=',')
    return csv_reader
```

Answer (score -1):

You are opening your file a context manager :

```
with open(...) as csv_file:
```

whithin which the file is open.
Howerver as far as you exit the context manager the file is closed automatically. and this is what happens after your `return` statement you are no longer in the context manager's context.

So all the operations you need to perform should be done under the `with open(...)` context

you can try:

```py
import csv


def get_data(file):
    with open(file,'r',encoding="ISO-8859-1") as csv_file:
        result = []
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file,delimiter=',')
        for i in csv_reader:
            result.append(i)
        return result
```